# Non-Trivial Elements

Tags: set

I'm attempting to make certain that I understand a particular concept from a current homework assignment.  In particular, we are given the Relation R = {A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N}, and the set F of functional dependencies for R.

```
{
    A->B
    AFE->GHI
    ACEF->JKMEB
    BD->LNB
    ACFEBD->GIK
}
```

What I am attempting to list is five non-trivial elements of F^+.  From my understanding, a dependency a->B is trivial if B is a subset of a.  So, from that, I have determined the following five non-trivial elements.

```
A->G
A->H
B->J
B->K
D->L
```

Is this the correct way to be looking at this problem?  Or do I misunderstand?

Comment: F of functional dependencies for R is not F->R too?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, sorry.

Comment: You want to do normalization?